# MatDialog - open a component passing a @Input()

Tags: angular, frontend

I need to open a component using the method `open(MyComponent, myConfig)` of the class MatDialog but with a `@Input()` added to the opened component. How can I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `data` property to pass the wanted datas.

```js
constructor(private dialog: MatDialog){}

this.diaog.open(YOUR_COMPONENT, {
  data: {} // What you want
  ... // Others properties
});
```

Then in YOUR_COMPONENT :

```js
constructor(@Inject(MAT_DIALOG_DATA) public data: any) {
  console.log(this.data);
}
```

https://material.angular.io/components/dialog/examples